# Setting message-ttl on queue level in MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

My goal is to set expiration time for every message deliver to specified queue eg. queue consumer is down so message is not consumed for more that 10 seconds so I want to automatically delete this message to not be consumed when consumer is up.
Exchanges and queues configuration creates automatically by MassTransit.

Is is possible to set `message-ttl` argument (described here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) for specified queueu in MassTransit?

I was looking for it in message consumer definition class (class deriving from ConsumerDefinition) but I found nothing in IReceiveEndpointConfigurator or IConsumerConfigurator available in ConfigureConsumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a consumer definition, you can pattern match the `configurator` argument to `IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator` and use it to set the queue argument for message TTL:

```cs
if(configurator is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rmq)
    rmq.SetQueueArgument("<argument name>", value);
```

Comment: It works. Argument message-ttl is added after recreating queue. But messages after expired ttl are visible in RabbitUI and consumed by MassTransit consumer. 
Do you know why these messages are not removed/expired and excluded from consuming by MassTransit?

Comment: Actually it seems that it is better to create new policy using RabbitMQ API described in table in here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html#how-policies-work